# place objects relative from point javascript

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, position

I have some javascript code that tries to place some objects above each other relative from a center point in this case `0,0`
The thing is that the amount of objects, size of the objects, and spacing between the objects are all variable.

See this image below that explains my situation the best (hopefully ;)):
[image]

So in this case the center point is the green dot and the mesh center positions are the yellow dots.
The `Mh` stands for Mesh Height (variable)
The `Sh` stands for Spacing height (variable)
I tried to show the logic behind the calculation of the yellow dots. But when i try to implement this in javascript it works for 3 lines but it breaks on other amount of lines.

This is what i have tried so far:

```
var data = {
    text : ["THE NEXT","POINT","OF VIEW"],
    size : 5,
    height : 2,
    curveSegments : 12,
    line_height : 2
};

function generateTextGeometry(mesh) {

    var scaled_lineheight = map_r(data.size, 2, 75, 0.5, 20);
    var y_start =  (0 - data.text.length * data.size / 2 - data.size / 2 - (data.text.length - 1) * scaled_lineheight)/2;
    var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

    loader.load( 'data/suisse_2.json', function ( font ) {

        for (var i = data.text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( data.text[i], {
                font: font,
                size: data.size,
                height: data.height,
                curveSegments: data.curveSegments
            });
            geometry.center();
            mesh.children[i].geometry = geometry;
            mesh.children[i].position.y = y_start;

            console.log(mesh.children[i].position);

            if (i < data.text.length) {
                y_start += (data.size + scaled_lineheight);
            }else{
                y_start += data.size;
            }
        }
        console.log('-----------------------');
    });
}
```

and When i console.log the position for 3 lines it is ok:

> p {x: 0, y: -6.301369863013699, z: 0}
>   p {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
>   p {x: 0, y: 6.301369863013699, z: 0}

but for any other amount of lines it is wrong:

> p {x: 0, y: -4.4006849315068495, z: 0}
>   p {x: 0, y: 1.9006849315068495, z: 0}

So my final question is how do i always get the yellow positions on the right location relative from the green center? What is wrong in my current logic?

If anything is unclear please let me know! So i can clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading my own question about 20 times. The light shined upon my brains haha.

So i just made a mistake when calculating the initial start Here is the updated line:

```
var y_start =  0 - (((data.text.length - 1) * data.size) + ((data.text.length - 1) * scaled_lineheight))/ 2;
```